# how to tell if a request/promise takes longer than 5 seconds to fulfill, angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I am a new developer, and am trying to check if a promise has not been resolved after 5 seconds. What is the most readable way to do this without creating a new directive/service/factory? this is what I tried, my main question is, am I setting the interval at the correct time, when the promise variable is instantiated?

```
  $scope.promiseTimeLimit = false;
      //if the promise does not return within 5 seconds, show a "service down" warning.
      var promise = service.checkValidRailCar($scope.railcar.number, $scope.railcar.initials);

      $interval(function () {
        $scope.promiseTimeLimit = true
      }, 5000)

      if ($scope.promiseTimeLimit) {
        $scope.message = {
          content: [{
            title: '',
            msg: 'The Service Is Down'
          }],
          type: 'error'
        };
        return;
      }
      promise.then(function (data) {
        if (!data.valid) {
          $scope.invalidData = true;
          $scope.message = {
            content: [{
              title: '',
              msg: 'Invalid: This is not a valid data and can not be created.'
            }],
            type: 'error'
          };
        } else {
          $scope.invalidData = false;
        }
      })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have set the interval correctly after the promise is instantiated. But, I don't think you want to use `$interval` here. You may want to use `$timeout`. Callback function in `$interval` will be called again and again unless you clear the `$interval`. Callback function in `$timeout` will be called only once. If you want to check only once if the promise is resolved in 5 seconds, you should use `$timeout`.

The second thing is about the following code:

```
if ($scope.promiseTimeLimit) {
    $scope.message = {
      content: [{
        title: '',
        msg: 'The Service Is Down'
      }],
      type: 'error'
    };
    return;
}
```

You need to keep this code inside the $timeout function. For better understanding, I am changing the variable name `$scope.promiseTimeLimit` to `$scope.promiseComplete` and initialized it as `$scope.promiseComplete = false`.

```
$timeout(function () {
    if(!$scope.promiseComplete) {
        $scope.message = {
          content: [{
            title: '',
            msg: 'The Service Is Down'
          }],
          type: 'error'
        };
     }
}, 5000);
```

Then, in the `promise.then` function(resolve), you need to set the `$scope.promiseComplete` to true.

```
promise.then(function (data) {
    $scope.promiseComplete = true;
    if (!data.valid) {
      ...
})
```

So, what is happening here? $timeout callback function will be called on or after 5 seconds. It will check if `$scope.promiseComplete` is false. If false, generate a warning message. If true, do nothing. In the `promise.then`, we set the `$scope.promiseComplete` to true. So, if `promise.then` function(resolve) sets `$scope.promiseComplete` to true before the $timeout callback function gets called, that means promise is completed before 5 seconds.

I have created a sample plunker to understand this behavior. You can have a look in [HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/vdd9adLwloai6hKZots7?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, a promise timeout should be implemented as a rejection and, like promisification, should be implmeneted at the lowest possible level.

In fact, an async timeout is effectively a promisification of `window.setTimeout()` in a *race* with whatever async service method you want to call.

You could write it like this, for example :

```
service.checkValidRailCarWithTimeout = function(t, railcarNumber, railcarInitials) {
    // range checks
    if(t === undefined || railcarNumber === undefined || railcarInitials === undefined) {
        return $q.reject(new RangeError('Invalid parameter(s)'));
    }
    // race - timeout versus service call
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
        var tRef = window.setTimeout(function() {
            reject(new Error('The Service Is Down');
        }, t);
        function kill() {
            window.clearTimeout(tRef);
        };
        service.checkValidRailCar(railcarNumber, railcarInitials).then(resolve, reject).then(kill, kill);
    });
};
```

And call as follows :

```
var promise = service.checkValidRailCarWithTimeout(5000, $scope.railcar.number, $scope.railcar.initials).then(function(data) {
    $scope.invalidData = !data.valid;
    if (!data.valid) {
        throw new Error('Invalid: This is not a valid data and can not be created.');
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    $scope.message = {
        content: [{
            title: '',
            msg: error.message
        }],
        type: 'error'
    };
});
```

Notes:

- The need for `$scope.promiseTimeLimit` disappears
- `kill()` is not strictly necessary but keeps things clean by clearing latent timouts that lost their race.
- The `$scope.message = ...` expression will display whichever message is delivered by `error`